# Overlapping dual monitors

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors

I have dual monitor setup and I was wondering if there's a way to specifiy an overlap between the 2 displays. Ideally, the area where the 2 monitors cross over would be repeated on both monitors (ven diagram-ish). Currently the display settings can only work when they're adjacent. On a side note, is it possible to seperate the monitors so that there's an assumed space between the displays? I'm currently running windows 7.

Comment: For those who would like to do this on linux: this is possible using command-line `xrandr` utility.

Comment: That would be cool! Good idea.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think it's possible to specify an overlap, other than using cloned displays (in which the entire display is cloned) or zoom (your specific video drivers might support this).

I'm pretty certain there's no way to configure an assumed space between the displays, because if a dialog or window opened up in the assumed space, you would have no way of noticing it or using it.

Comment: What exactly would you do with an "assumed space"  (other than lose things)?

Comment: @James: my point exactly.  ;)  The original question asks if there is a way to configure the monitors with an assumed space.

Comment: Assumed space would be nice with e.g. 5 monitors. A row of 3 and a row of 2 (with the hole in the middle).

Comment: @Hennes Your 5-monitor example makes sense and is supported but rather than "assumed space" there are hard boundaries around the hole (though I could be misunderstanding what was meant by "assumed space"). Regardless, as I understand it, the 5-monitor case is different from the case of exactly 2 monitors as defined in the original question.

Answer (score 1):

If all you are looking for is for the background to look right, you could just edit the background picture so that when you apply it, it looks like there is a space there.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about this stuff, but I once heard something about 'powerwall' stuff.  Apparently it exists, but you need the right kind of graphics card.

Answer (score 0):

Change the resolution and move the entire image. I'm pretty sure you can do that through the NVIDIA control panel. Don't take my word for it.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please read the question again carefully. Your answer does **not** answer the original question.